# What is a radar projection?

Tags: coordinate-system

Trying to overlay a radar image(radar projection) on a mercator projected map, but have no idea about what a radar projection is.

So here are my quesions:

What is a radar projection?

What's its forward/backward formula?

Does proj4 or gdal/ogr support this projection?

Comment: There are multiple radar presentation formats (from the A-scope up to more "understandable" formats). It might help if you can edit your question (using the edit link above) to tell us more about your data. For example, where did you get the data? Can you make a sample public?

Comment: @BradHards , the radar image is a PPI display and already scan converted. I've been only told it's a "standard radar projection". So I think its just some normal raster under some projection.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm not convinced that there is any such thing as a standard for radar projections, so you'll need to go back to the source, or perhaps consider posting a sample that someone may recognise.

Comment: It is striking that Google cannot find *any* instance, anywhere, of the phrase "standard radar projection"!

Answer (score 1):

The radar projection is an azimuthal projection given as this
   x = R sin (azimuth)
   y = R cos (azimuth)
(Azimuth increasing clockwise from north, and R is range).   On the map, straight radial lines from the radar are along a constant radar azimuth.  The exact type of azimuthal projection depends on what "R" is.

If R is a great circle distance (i.e. to the point on the surface under the radar beam) then this is an oblique azimuthal equidistant projection.
If the distance R is along the radar beam itself then things become complicated in because the answer depends on the elevation angle of the antenna and how much the atmosphere will bend the beam.  To a first approximation, if the radar's antenna elevation angle is 0 (horizontal) then R along the beam makes the projection equivalent to an gnomonic projection with the Earth's radius, Re, replaced by 4/3 Re.

So unfortunately you need to know what R was used in the map (grid) creation.  In practice if one chooses any azimuthal projection the error will be negligible is within about 100km of a radar and for most purposes you will probably be OK to 200km.